# json decoder can't decode json data swift

Tags: json, swift, urlsession, jsondecoder

in my code I am not able to decode my response which I am getting from api.
I am finding data , but my decoder can't able to decode this, I have tried to find the issue , but I am not able to find out this.

My Code is :

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://wsapi.easyservice.xyz/api/v1/carts/2")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
        request.addValue("Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImI0YzFkOTRhN2ZmN2I0OGE1MTI3ZWMyZTAxYzJhYzMxNzRkODIxYjVkYTlhMTE3N2NlNTUxODViNTZjZDEyNjY2NWI2ZjVhOGU2NTM1ZDExIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiYjRjMWQ5NGE3ZmY3YjQ4YTUxMjdlYzJlMDFjMmFjMzE3NGQ4MjFiNWRhOWExMTc3Y2U1NTE4NWI1NmNkMTI2NjY1YjZmNWE4ZTY1MzVkMTEiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDU1MDk1MDEsIm5iZiI6MTYwNTUwOTUwMSwiZXhwIjoxNjM3MDQ1NTAxLCJzdWIiOiI0NTIiLCJzY29wZXMiOltdfQ.cHR-jRG4atU8DtwqiQtxV9vjRg4CMR9dYH8AGpgKgOmbylSLlf8eYf76LmwVOZl9Ii1uxHXvK95_43suYuO_6REE_pMEgRKELxM9LZVPSt6VboXENqwBZ_1GCu4nobBUPPqC56SXYqTVaLlTSjts7O3kpXrPqhrEIWV0UQYq9KS6bUFMkQuuyDrXoL6JVuJ-ntUzU42QgXjaQ0usQah3-gJZGAB684bp6LP3_RTInuIDKarGERPKHIFz94V_jvpkixKBUQW1uDJpcSh9v2ZR1PVlQ1pMaYGaZN50OrTkqY9NTi16PpUhOrmzCcXFLxWC4S-s2FDlXfPZNS-1kEIguS38ecydyBW_FHSzJQFQHZ5STTNiLxB8B5-6OUwEaaXBl9XuJJBlcmUrMiQNjqb2TXL9ZNw1R6Htqgrn2En0RjgzuWXSLui1PgkyRJMifg2cphPpQlNhgkXqZrPz27_xp8CCfUjdiEFEWFdFj-4_grRPjLXA48alG6KeFGi_Vu65rVNCz9yF5M4U43G9KJZCg8-nppKZ623OvE4YxU8IS7SuTuQIHChFPaVef-D7GYLnZEPl7L7bo5IuUiwZ67wP0zieKsEya3_LDNy_tUG48k-y5KTl0OOIn4GtmDdCAK4qKcAC_0OjWmktesJRbgh3Nm9O_CIl_DBUZ89fMks0SsA", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            
            if let jsonResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(GetItCartModel.self, from: data!) {
                print(jsonResponse)
            }
          guard let data = data else {
            print(String(describing: error))
            
            return
          }
          print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
          
        }

        task.resume()
```

and I am using this model as GetItCartModel

```
// MARK: - GetItCartModel
struct GetItCartModel: Codable {
    var success: Bool?
    var message: String?
    var data: GetItCartModelDataClass?
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct GetItCartModelDataClass: Codable {
    var id, userID, serviceID: Int?
    var createdAt, updatedAt: String?
    var items: [GetItCartModelItem]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case userID = "user_id"
        case serviceID = "service_id"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
        case items
    }
}

// MARK: - Item
struct GetItCartModelItem: Codable {
    var id, cartID: Int?
    var details: GetItCartModelDetails?
    var attachments: JSONNull?
    var quantity, createdAt, updatedAt: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case cartID = "cart_id"
        case details, attachments, quantity
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
    }
}

// MARK: - Details
struct GetItCartModelDetails: Codable {
    var brandID: Int?
    var brandName: String?
    var icategoryIdd: Int?
    var categoryName, endDate: String?
    var id, orderItemPrice: Int?
    var product: Product?
    var quantity: Int?
    var startDate: String?
    var totalDays: Int?
    var typeID: Int?
    var typeName: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case brandID = "brandId"
        case brandName, icategoryIdd, categoryName, endDate, id, orderItemPrice, product, quantity, startDate, totalDays
        case typeID = "typeId"
        case typeName
    }
}



// MARK: - Product
struct GetItCartModelProduct: Codable {
    var categorizableID: Int?
    var createdAt, productDescription: String?
    var id: Int?
    var price: String?
    var thumbnail: String?
    var title, updatedAt: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case categorizableID = "categorizable_id"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case productDescription = "description"
        case id, price, thumbnail, title
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
    }
}
```

do you please help me to find the actual issue which I am facing to convert my response to this model .

Note: Here is postman response JSON

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "items list",
    "data": {
        "id": 23,
        "user_id": 452,
        "service_id": 2,
        "created_at": "2020-11-16 13:21:36",
        "updated_at": "2020-11-16 13:21:36",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 54,
                "cart_id": 23,
                "details": {
                    "brandId": 44,
                    "brandName": "Apple",
                    "icategoryIdd": 41,
                    "categoryName": "Mobile Equipment",
                    "endDate": "2020-12-26",
                    "id": 0,
                    "orderItemPrice": 4920,
                    "product": {
                        "categorizable_id": 44,
                        "created_at": "2020-07-24 05:46:07",
                        "description": "Description",
                        "id": 11,
                        "price": "120.00",
                        "thumbnail": "https://hexamatics.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/app/photos/product/kkoBnHm7cqjWzPTh4nPdaxuPaTDylNdNDqlCFKLz.jpeg",
                        "title": "Test product",
                        "updated_at": "2020-08-25 12:14:21"
                    },
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "startDate": "2020-11-16",
                    "totalDays": 41,
                    "typeId": 42,
                    "typeName": "Display"
                },
                "attachments": null,
                "quantity": "1",
                "created_at": "2020-11-16 13:21:36",
                "updated_at": "2020-11-16 13:21:36"
            },
            {
                "id": 97,
                "cart_id": 23,
                "details": {
                    "categoryName": "Mobile Equipment",
                    "startDate": "2020-11-18 09:20:32 +0000",
                    "brandId": "44",
                    "product": {
                        "thumbnail": "https://hexamatics.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/app/photos/product/kkoBnHm7cqjWzPTh4nPdaxuPaTDylNdNDqlCFKLz.jpeg",
                        "categorizable_id": 44,
                        "created_at": "2020-07-24 05:46:07",
                        "title": "Test product",
                        "updated_at": "2020-08-25 12:14:21",
                        "description": "Description",
                        "id": 11,
                        "price": "120.00"
                    },
                    "icategoryIdd": "41",
                    "typeId": "42",
                    "typeName": "Display",
                    "brandName": "Apple",
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "endDate": "2020-11-18 09:20:36 +0000"
                },
                "attachments": null,
                "quantity": "1",
                "created_at": "2020-11-18 09:20:51",
                "updated_at": "2020-11-18 09:20:51"
            },
            {
                "id": 98,
                "cart_id": 23,
                "details": {
                    "brandId": 44,
                    "brandName": "Apple",
                    "icategoryIdd": 41,
                    "categoryName": "Mobile Equipment",
                    "endDate": "2020-11-18",
                    "id": 0,
                    "orderItemPrice": 120,
                    "product": {
                        "categorizable_id": 44,
                        "created_at": "2020-07-24 05:46:07",
                        "description": "Description",
                        "id": 11,
                        "price": "120.00",
                        "thumbnail": "https://hexamatics.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/app/photos/product/kkoBnHm7cqjWzPTh4nPdaxuPaTDylNdNDqlCFKLz.jpeg",
                        "title": "Test product",
                        "updated_at": "2020-08-25 12:14:21"
                    },
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "startDate": "2020-11-18",
                    "totalDays": 1,
                    "typeId": 42,
                    "typeName": "Display"
                },
                "attachments": null,
                "quantity": "1",
                "created_at": "2020-11-18 10:16:18",
                "updated_at": "2020-11-18 10:16:18"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we do that when we don't know what the response (json) is? As a first step though is that you should never do `try?` when decoding json downloaded from some api. Use `try` with a `do/catch` and print the error in the catch, `catch { print(error) }`. Maybe this even will help you resolve this issue yourself :). Another thing I just noticed is that you first try to decode the data then afterwards checks if you received any data, this should of course be done in the opposite order.

Comment: Thanks , I have edited the question with json data , but here I am getting typeMismatch error when I am printing error. 
but I am not able to make my entities as like response . I am getting int , but when I am defining int its not decoding with error type mismatch

Answer (score 0):

I have make a solution , I have used JSONAny type where its showing typeMismatch error.
like I have made a model:

```
struct ITBase : Codable {
    let success : Bool?
    let message : String?
    let data : ITData?
    
}


struct ITData : Codable {
    let id : JSONAny?
    let user_id : JSONAny?
    let service_id : JSONAny?
    let created_at : String?
    let updated_at : String?
    let items : [ITItems]?
    
    
}


struct ITDetails : Codable {
    let brandId : JSONAny?
    let brandName : String?
    let icategoryIdd : JSONAny?
    let categoryName : String?
    let endDate : String?
    let id : JSONAny?
    let orderItemPrice : JSONAny?
    let product : ITProduct?
    let quantity : JSONAny?
    let startDate : String?
    let totalDays : JSONAny?
    let typeId : JSONAny?
    let typeName : String?
    
}


struct ITItems : Codable {
    let id : JSONAny?
    let cart_id : JSONAny?
    let details : ITDetails?
    let attachments : JSONAny?
    let quantity : JSONAny?
    let created_at : String?
    let updated_at : String?
    
}

struct ITProduct : Codable {
    let categorizable_id : JSONAny?
    let created_at : String?
    let description : String?
    let id : JSONAny?
    let price : JSONAny?
    let thumbnail : String?
    let title : String?
    let updated_at : String?
    
    
}
```

but I don't know is the solution good or bad . if you have any better solution you may suggest me.

Comment: What is this, SwiftyJSON or? I would not recommend a solution as this because you will only push the problem ahead of you and you are going to need to add extra logic whenever you want to access any of the properties that are of the type JSONAny.

Comment: I have got it now , thanks for your help @JoakimDanielson

Comment: incorrect parameters. brandId, typeID may have different types: String or Int according the request.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the json you get isn't very consistent and some integer values are given both as strings and integers.

So you need to add a custom `init(from:)` to the `GetItCartModelDetails` type and handle both scenarios there. I started writing one as per below but you must of course add all properties of `GetItCartModelDetails` to this init method

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    if let temp = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .brandID) {
        brandID = temp
    } else {
        brandID = Int(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .brandID)) ?? 0
    }
    brandName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .brandName)
    if let temp = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .icategoryIdd) {
        icategoryIdd = temp
    } else {
        icategoryIdd = Int(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .icategoryIdd)) ?? 0
    }
    categoryName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .categoryName)
    if let temp = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .quantity) {
        quantity = temp
    } else {
        quantity = Int(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .quantity)) ?? 0
    }
    //add all other properties here.
}
```

You have set allmost all your properties to be optional which is wrong, only let the properties you *know* can be nil be declared as optional.

I am setting the property to 0 as you can see if the string can not be converted to Int. This is a simplified solution and you should consider if it is better to throw an error or maybe to let the property be optional. This of course depends on what the property means and how relevant it is.